# How do i create a tab page on facebook where the page is dynamicly generated with a url GET

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have created an app on facebook which uses a page on my website.

The page on my website is generated using a get in the url.
for example https://mypage.com//test.php?k=ccjBGNJSCd

Im having an "intergrate" button which brings up a facebook dialog, like this:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=345672345&redirect_uri=https://mypage.com/return.php

But I don't know how to send the get code "ccjBGNJSCd" to the tab page.
I can't put it into the app settings because it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: `...&redirect_uri=https://mypage.com/return.php?k=ccjBGNJSCd`

Comment: You can not pass dynamic data into a page tab that way – you set the initial page tab URL _once_ in your app dashboard, and that’s the URL that will be used for _all_ pages your app might get embedded in. –/– What do you need that “dynamic” value for? If you just want to display different content based on the page the app is running in – then read the page id from the `signed_request` parameter that is posted to your app on initial load into the page tab iframe.